# Using .net core web api from sitecore root

Tags: webapi

We are building JSS application in SSR mode. 
We need to build an api which will be running from sitecore root.
Can I build API using .net core or only .net framework is supported when running it from sitecore root.
Another query if using .net framework, can we use 4.8 as it is not in compatibility table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Can I build API using .net core or only .net framework is supported when running it from sitecore root."

No , you need to rely on .NET framework for your API, if you plan to host the service from within Sitecore Website. IMO you should move away from the Sitecore root and deploy your service in a seperate website , this way you can leverage .NET core as well.

Since the question is unclear on what your service does, You could try using Sitecore ItemService API if you need data from within Sitecore Items

Comment: Thanks Abhay. API is to log end user (from jss app) in sitecore virtually and setup user context (custom) to evaluate personalization. It will be used from jss app while executing layout service. JSS app is running from different server n connecting to sitecore in headless mode. Not sure if possible to run api outside sitecore root, as we need to authenticate end user (virtually).